# Listview onitem click data into arraylist

Tags: android, listview

When I click on list on product1 I get `[product1]`, similarly when clicking on product2 I get `[product2]`, but I want this: if I click on product 1 and then product 2, output has to be: `[product1, product2]`.

```
public class MyListFrag extends ListFragment {

    Context context;    
    ListView listView;
    List<Content> rowItems;

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Product1", "Product2", "product3" };
    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] { "Android", "iphone", "blackberry"};



    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();

        rowItems = new ArrayList<Content>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            Content item = new Content( titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);         

        }       

        setListAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), rowItems));
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, final int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);       

          String data1 =rowItems.get(position).getTitle();    
           System.out.println("Title"+data1);

          String data2 =rowItems.get(position).getDescriptio();       
          System.out.println("Descr"+data1);


          ArrayList<String> titleArray = new ArrayList<String>();         
          TitleArray.add(data1);      

                  ArrayList<String> desArray = new ArrayList<String>();       
          desArray.add(data2);

          System.out.println("Title::::"+titleArray);         
          System.out.println("descr:::"+desArray);   


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified this class and declared arrayList(titleArray and desArray) globally.Now it should work.

public class MyListFrag extends ListFragment {

```
Context context;    
ListView listView;
List<Content> rowItems;

ArrayList<String> titleArray = new ArrayList<String>();  
ArrayList<String> desArray = new ArrayList<String>();      

public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Product1", "Product2", "product3" };
public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] { "Android", "iphone", "blackberry"};



public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();

    rowItems = new ArrayList<Content>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        Content item = new Content( titles[i], descriptions[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);         

    }       

    setListAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), rowItems));
}


public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, final int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);       

      String data1 =rowItems.get(position).getTitle();    
       System.out.println("Title"+data1);

      String data2 =rowItems.get(position).getDescriptio();       
      System.out.println("Descr"+data1);



      titleArray.add(data1);      
      desArray.add(data2);

      System.out.println("Title::::"+titleArray);         
      System.out.println("descr:::"+desArray);   


}
```

}

Comment: @geet You should have answered more descriptively so that user2042881 would have understood.

Comment: @geet Hold on..I didnt copy your answer rather i should say any android developer could have pointed this fault.

Answer (score 1):

Just Track the position where user had click.

```
ArrayList<Integer> posArray =new ArrayList<Integer> ();
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, final int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);       
     posArray.add(Integer.parseInt(position));
             // rest of the code   
    
    
        }
```

You can get all list of data by using `posArray` like

```
for(int i=0;i<posArray.size();i++){
System.out.println(String.ValueOf(titles[posArray.get(i)]));
}
```

Or Simply you can use `titles[posArray.get(i)])` On onListItemClick, too.

**EDIT**

Try to initialize globally to

```
 ArrayList<String> titleArray = new ArrayList<String>();         

    
 ArrayList<String> desArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

& then add them into onListItemClick method

```
             TitleArray.add(data1);      
              desArray.add(data2);
    
              System.out.println("Title::::"+titleArray);         
              System.out.println("descr:::"+desArray);
```

Comment: public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, final int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id); 

posArray =new ArrayList<Integer> (); 
  
  posArray.add(position);  
   
    for(int i=0;i<posArray.size();i++){
     System.out.println("title"+ titles[posArray.get(i)]);
  
    }           
   
   } 

getting as product1 when clicked on firstitem and similarly product2 when clicked on second item.

Comment: remove  posArray =new ArrayList<Integer> (); from onListItemClick. As it will re initialize when user click on list

Answer (score 0):

Your `titleArray` and `desArray` are local variables, they need to be moved out of `onListItemClick` method